# How do I change this add-on so it will automatically iterate over all diffuse textures in a.blend file

Tags: python, materials, blend-files

** It is a simple add-on that I paid the guy off fiver to make for me, and it's supposed just select all the diffuse image texture nodes in the file
(the ones plugged into the principled BDSF base color node)
so that viewport will look good in solid mode (meaning use the diffuse texture instead of the normal map or ambient occlusion map to display your model in the viewport in solid mode) if you have texture selected in shader properties that is.

I'm pretty sure you guys know what I mean.

Right now it uses this line as far as I could tell to iterate over the textures in the file.. To decide which node to select... so all the diffuse textures must be named appropriately.

```
if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE' and (('diffuse' in node.image.name) or ('color' in node.image.name) or ('albedo' in node.image.name)):
                    node.select = True
```

I'd rather this addon be able to work on any diffuse texture whether it's named right or not because I think that blender could tell that it's a diffuse texture and select it if the addon is written right.. because the diffuse texture is always plugged into a base color node... If anybody could help me with this I'd appreciate it!

the code is below(only init.py no other files were necessary to create this add-on)
or if anybody has any advice to make this add on work even better and can edit my file and show me what they did so I can learn better for the future I'd appreciate it!  **

````
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTIBILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# This addon was created with the Serpens - Visual Scripting Addon.
# This code is generated from nodes and is not intended for manual editing.
# You can find out more about Serpens at <https://blendermarket.com/products/serpens>.


bl_info = {
    "name": "Texture Viewer",
    "description": "",
    "author": "Rafael Ribeiro",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (3, 30, 0),
    "location": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "3D View"
}


###############   IMPORTS
import bpy
from bpy.utils import previews
import os
import math


###############   INITALIZE VARIABLES
###############   SERPENS FUNCTIONS
def exec_line(line):
    exec(line)

def sn_print(tree_name, *args):
    if tree_name in bpy.data.node_groups:
        item = bpy.data.node_groups[tree_name].sn_graphs[0].prints.add()
        for arg in args:
            item.value += str(arg) + ";;;"
        if bpy.context and bpy.context.screen:
            for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
                area.tag_redraw()
    print(*args)

def sn_cast_string(value):
    return str(value)

def sn_cast_boolean(value):
    if type(value) == tuple:
        for data in value:
            if bool(data):
                return True
        return False
    return bool(value)

def sn_cast_float(value):
    if type(value) == str:
        try:
            value = float(value)
            return value
        except:
            return float(bool(value))
    elif type(value) == tuple:
        return float(value[0])
    elif type(value) == list:
        return float(len(value))
    elif not type(value) in [float, int, bool]:
        try:
            value = len(value)
            return float(value)
        except:
            return float(bool(value))
    return float(value)

def sn_cast_int(value):
    return int(sn_cast_float(value))

def sn_cast_boolean_vector(value, size):
    if type(value) in [str, bool, int, float]:
        return_value = []
        for i in range(size):
            return_value.append(bool(value))
        return tuple(return_value)
    elif type(value) == tuple:
        return_value = []
        for i in range(size):
            return_value.append(bool(value[i]) if len(value) > i else bool(value[0]))
        return tuple(return_value)
    elif type(value) == list:
        return sn_cast_boolean_vector(tuple(value), size)
    else:
        try:
            value = tuple(value)
            return sn_cast_boolean_vector(value, size)
        except:
            return sn_cast_boolean_vector(bool(value), size)

def sn_cast_float_vector(value, size):
    if type(value) in [str, bool, int, float]:
        return_value = []
        for i in range(size):
            return_value.append(sn_cast_float(value))
        return tuple(return_value)
    elif type(value) == tuple:
        return_value = []
        for i in range(size):
            return_value.append(sn_cast_float(value[i]) if len(value) > i else sn_cast_float(value[0]))
        return tuple(return_value)
    elif type(value) == list:
        return sn_cast_float_vector(tuple(value), size)
    else:
        try:
            value = tuple(value)
            return sn_cast_float_vector(value, size)
        except:
            return sn_cast_float_vector(sn_cast_float(value), size)

def sn_cast_int_vector(value, size):
    return tuple(map(int, sn_cast_float_vector(value, size)))

def sn_cast_color(value, use_alpha):
    length = 4 if use_alpha else 3
    value = sn_cast_float_vector(value, length)
    tuple_list = []
    for data in range(length):
        data = value[data] if len(value) > data else value[0]
        tuple_list.append(sn_cast_float(min(1, max(0, data))))
    return tuple(tuple_list)

def sn_cast_list(value):
    if type(value) in [str, tuple, list]:
        return list(value)
    elif type(value) in [int, float, bool]:
        return [value]
    else:
        try:
            value = list(value)
            return value
        except:
            return [value]

def sn_cast_blend_data(value):
    if hasattr(value, "bl_rna"):
        return value
    elif type(value) in [tuple, bool, int, float, list]:
        return None
    elif type(value) == str:
        try:
            value = eval(value)
            return value
        except:
            return None
    else:
        return None

def sn_cast_enum(string, enum_values):
    for item in enum_values:
        if item[1] == string:
            return item[0]
        elif item[0] == string.upper():
            return item[0]
    return string


###############   IMPERATIVE CODE
###############   EVALUATED CODE
#######   Texture Viewer
class SNA_OT_New_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "sna.new_operator"
    bl_label = "New Operator"
    bl_description = ""
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}


    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            pass
        except Exception as exc:
            print(str(exc) + " | Error in execute function of New Operator")
        return {"FINISHED"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        try:
            pass # All_Texture Script Start
            import bpy
            import os
            os.system('cls')
            print('start')
            for mat in bpy.data.materials:
                print(mat.name)
                if ('Stroke' in mat.name):
                    print('dot material skip')
                    continue
                node_tree = mat.node_tree
                for node in node_tree.nodes:
                    if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE' and (('diffuse' in node.image.name) or ('color' in node.image.name) or ('albedo' in node.image.name)):
                        node.select = True
                        node_tree.nodes.active = node
                    else:
                        node.select = False
            for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
                if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    area.tag_redraw()
            pass # All_Texture Script End
        except Exception as exc:
            print(str(exc) + " | Error in invoke function of New Operator")
        return self.execute(context)

def sn_append_panel_67E9B(self,context):
    try:
        layout = self.layout
        op = layout.operator("sna.new_operator",text=r"Fix Texture View",emboss=True,depress=False,icon_value=126)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(str(exc) + " | Error in View3D View3D Properties when adding to panel")


###############   REGISTER ICONS
def sn_register_icons():
    icons = []
    bpy.types.Scene.texture_viewer_icons = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    icons_dir = os.path.join( os.path.dirname( __file__ ), "icons" )
    for icon in icons:
        bpy.types.Scene.texture_viewer_icons.load( icon, os.path.join( icons_dir, icon + ".png" ), 'IMAGE' )

def sn_unregister_icons():
    bpy.utils.previews.remove( bpy.types.Scene.texture_viewer_icons )


###############   REGISTER PROPERTIES
def sn_register_properties():
    pass

def sn_unregister_properties():
    pass


###############   REGISTER ADDON
def register():
    sn_register_icons()
    sn_register_properties()
    bpy.utils.register_class(SNA_OT_New_Operator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_view3d_properties.append(sn_append_panel_67E9B)


###############   UNREGISTER ADDON
def unregister():
    sn_unregister_icons()
    sn_unregister_properties()
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_view3d_properties.remove(sn_append_panel_67E9B)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SNA_OT_New_Operator)```















OK, Edit:  I input your function into the code and I think I did it correctly I evaluated it as an or statement next to the OR statements that check for the diffuse file names but the code is not working... I'm trying to run it on a cube with a diffuse texture and a normal map and it's not selecting the base color node... and all the textures on the house in this .blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LkPZ0BSzAJU23lFjjMyWHKHmOvZWcjVr/view?usp=sharing and its not selecting the base color node on any of the materials....can you help with this? 


here is latest code:

```# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTIBILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# This addon was created with the Serpens - Visual Scripting Addon.
# This code is generated from nodes and is not intended for manual editing.
# You can find out more about Serpens at <https://blendermarket.com/products/serpens>.


bl_info = {
    "name": "Texture Viewer",
    "description": "",
    "author": "Rafael Ribeiro",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (3, 30, 0),
    "location": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "3D View"
}


###############   IMPORTS
import bpy
from bpy.utils import previews
import os
import math


###############   INITALIZE VARIABLES
###############   SERPENS FUNCTIONS
def exec_line(line):
    exec(line)

def sn_print(tree_name, *args):
    if tree_name in bpy.data.node_groups:
        item = bpy.data.node_groups[tree_name].sn_graphs[0].prints.add()
        for arg in args:
            item.value += str(arg) + ";;;"
        if bpy.context and bpy.context.screen:
            for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
                area.tag_redraw()
    print(*args)

def sn_cast_string(value):
    return str(value)

def sn_cast_boolean(value):
    if type(value) == tuple:
        for data in value:
            if bool(data):
                return True
        return False
    return bool(value)

def sn_cast_float(value):
    if type(value) == str:
        try:
            value = float(value)
            return value
        except:
            return float(bool(value))
    elif type(value) == tuple:
        return float(value[0])
    elif type(value) == list:
        return float(len(value))
    elif not type(value) in [float, int, bool]:
        try:
            value = len(value)
            return float(value)
        except:
            return float(bool(value))
    return float(value)

def sn_cast_int(value):
    return int(sn_cast_float(value))

def sn_cast_boolean_vector(value, size):
    if type(value) in [str, bool, int, float]:
        return_value = []
        for i in range(size):
            return_value.append(bool(value))
        return tuple(return_value)
    elif type(value) == tuple:
        return_value = []
        for i in range(size):
            return_value.append(bool(value[i]) if len(value) > i else bool(value[0]))
        return tuple(return_value)
    elif type(value) == list:
        return sn_cast_boolean_vector(tuple(value), size)
    else:
        try:
            value = tuple(value)
            return sn_cast_boolean_vector(value, size)
        except:
            return sn_cast_boolean_vector(bool(value), size)

def sn_cast_float_vector(value, size):
    if type(value) in [str, bool, int, float]:
        return_value = []
        for i in range(size):
            return_value.append(sn_cast_float(value))
        return tuple(return_value)
    elif type(value) == tuple:
        return_value = []
        for i in range(size):
            return_value.append(sn_cast_float(value[i]) if len(value) > i else sn_cast_float(value[0]))
        return tuple(return_value)
    elif type(value) == list:
        return sn_cast_float_vector(tuple(value), size)
    else:
        try:
            value = tuple(value)
            return sn_cast_float_vector(value, size)
        except:
            return sn_cast_float_vector(sn_cast_float(value), size)

def sn_cast_int_vector(value, size):
    return tuple(map(int, sn_cast_float_vector(value, size)))

def sn_cast_color(value, use_alpha):
    length = 4 if use_alpha else 3
    value = sn_cast_float_vector(value, length)
    tuple_list = []
    for data in range(length):
        data = value[data] if len(value) > data else value[0]
        tuple_list.append(sn_cast_float(min(1, max(0, data))))
    return tuple(tuple_list)

def sn_cast_list(value):
    if type(value) in [str, tuple, list]:
        return list(value)
    elif type(value) in [int, float, bool]:
        return [value]
    else:
        try:
            value = list(value)
            return value
        except:
            return [value]

def sn_cast_blend_data(value):
    if hasattr(value, "bl_rna"):
        return value
    elif type(value) in [tuple, bool, int, float, list]:
        return None
    elif type(value) == str:
        try:
            value = eval(value)
            return value
        except:
            return None
    else:
        return None

def sn_cast_enum(string, enum_values):
    for item in enum_values:
        if item[1] == string:
            return item[0]
        elif item[0] == string.upper():
            return item[0]
    return string


###############   IMPERATIVE CODE
###############   EVALUATED CODE
#######   Texture Viewer
class SNA_OT_New_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "sna.new_operator"
    bl_label = "New Operator"
    bl_description = ""
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}


    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            pass
        except Exception as exc:
            print(str(exc) + " | Error in execute function of New Operator")
        return {"FINISHED"}

    def detect_diffuse_texture_node(node):
        if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
            for link in node.outputs[0].links:
                if link.to_socket.name == "Base Color":
                    return True
        return false
                
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        try:
            pass # All_Texture Script Start
            import bpy
            import os
            os.system('cls')
            print('start')
            for mat in bpy.data.materials:
                print(mat.name)
                if ('Stroke' in mat.name):
                    print('dot material skip')
                    continue
                node_tree = mat.node_tree
                for node in node_tree.nodes:
                    if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE' and (('diffuse' in node.image.name) or ('color' in node.image.name) or ('albedo' in node.image.name) or detect_diffuse_texture_node(node.image.name.to_socket.name())):
                        node.select = True
                        node_tree.nodes.active = node
                    else:
                        node.select = False
            for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
                if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    area.tag_redraw()
            pass # All_Texture Script End
        except Exception as exc:
            print(str(exc) + " | Error in invoke function of New Operator")
        return self.execute(context)

def sn_append_panel_67E9B(self,context):
    try:
        layout = self.layout
        op = layout.operator("sna.new_operator",text=r"Fix Texture View",emboss=True,depress=False,icon_value=126)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(str(exc) + " | Error in View3D View3D Properties when adding to panel")


###############   REGISTER ICONS
def sn_register_icons():
    icons = []
    bpy.types.Scene.texture_viewer_icons = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    icons_dir = os.path.join( os.path.dirname( __file__ ), "icons" )
    for icon in icons:
        bpy.types.Scene.texture_viewer_icons.load( icon, os.path.join( icons_dir, icon + ".png" ), 'IMAGE' )

def sn_unregister_icons():
    bpy.utils.previews.remove( bpy.types.Scene.texture_viewer_icons )


###############   REGISTER PROPERTIES
def sn_register_properties():
    pass

def sn_unregister_properties():
    pass


###############   REGISTER ADDON
def register():
    sn_register_icons()
    sn_register_properties()
    bpy.utils.register_class(SNA_OT_New_Operator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_view3d_properties.append(sn_append_panel_67E9B)


###############   UNREGISTER ADDON
def unregister():
    sn_unregister_icons()
    sn_unregister_properties()
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_view3d_properties.remove(sn_append_panel_67E9B)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SNA_OT_New_Operator)```
````

Answer (score 3):

You can detect the simple case of whether the color socket of the Image Texture node is connected to a socket named "Base Color" with

```
def detect_diffuse_texture_node(node):
    if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
        for link in node.outputs[0].links:
            if link.to_socket.name == "Base Color":
                return True

    return False
```

Comment: Maybe `if "Color" in link.to_socket.name:` is more robust since it will work on diffuse, glossy, glass, etc. shaders too

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, and normal maps too!

Comment: Hehe, you're right, good point. :)

Comment: @scurest please see edit

Comment: Can you tell me how to add this to my code so it'll iterate over all the diffuse textures in the file and select the base color image node